# Product Movement Algorithm Ranking (Based on Units Sold and Net Income)

Tags: php, python, mysql, algorithm, ranking

I am not totally sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Hopefully someone will have an answer or could give some advice.

I run a small shop that sells commodities. I have a program / spreadsheet that will list the top moving items.

I can sort this information by total number of units sold:

```
Product 1, 15  
Product 2, 12  
Product 3, 7
```

... or by total value in sales:

```
Product 2, $250.00   
Product 1, $75.00  
Product 3, $30.00
```

I would like to create a combined rank between these two values. I have programming (PHP, Python, Perl, etc.) and database experience. I was wondering if there is some way to identify the top movers with a combined value of income and units. For example, Product 1 sells more units, but brings in less money. Perhaps product 2 is more important. Maybe a points based system where 1.5 points might be given for each unit sold and 2 points for each dollar. (monetary being slightly more important)

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing you need to think about is "what exactly you want these ranks to mean". A simple approach would be to sort them in both of the above ways (in increasing manner) and assign a score like `units_sold_rank * 1.5 + total_money_gathered_rank * 2.0` and sort them based on that. In your case that will push Product 2 on the top with a score of `1.5` (or `4.0` depending if you index from `0` or from `1`), while Product 1 will have a score of `2.0` (or `5.5`)

Comment: Are you are asking for business algorithm rather than code? If yes, try googling or binging "ABC pareto analysis inventory", common technique to rank as you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, then this query should be pretty close for what you're looking for:

```
SELECT Product, 
  CAST(1.5*UnitsSold as DECIMAL) + 2*DollarsSold OverallRank
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY OverallRank DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973bb/2)

If not, the same concept should work in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not also sure if this is the right place where ask this kind of questions. It seems your are asking for algorithm or **some standard business rules** but for final code.

Well, I post an approach to raise new ideas. I construct a list of algorithms and test for top values:

```
import math

fs = [
 ('Plain coef',    lambda m: math.log(m[1]* units_coef)  
                           + math.log(m[2]* money_coef)  ),
 ('Coef into log', lambda m: m[1]* units_coef 
                           + m[2]* money_coef                       ),
 ('Coef out log',  lambda m: math.log(m[1])* units_coef  
                           + math.log(m[2]) * money_coef ),
 ('Coef out log2',  lambda m: math.log(m[1],2)* units_coef  
                           + math.log(m[2],2) * money_coef ),
]

movings = [ ( 'product1', 1500,    75.00 ),
            ( 'product2',    2, 90000.00 ),
            ( 'product3', 1200,  8000.00 ),
            ( 'product4',    6,  4000.00 ),
            ( 'product5',  500,  1000.00 ),
            ( 'product6',  800,  1200.00 ),
            ( 'product7',  300,   800.00 ),
           ]

units_coef = 1.1
money_coef = 0.04

for (n,f) in fs:
    print ''
    print n
    print '==============================================='
    for i in sorted( movings, 
                     key = lambda m: f(m) , 
                     reverse=True)[:3]:
        print i, f(i)
```

Results:

```
$ python solds.py 

Plain coef
===============================================
('product3', 1200, 8000.0) 12.9537080114
('product6', 800, 1200.0) 10.6511229184
('product5', 500, 1000.0) 9.99879773234

Coef into log
===============================================
('product2', 2, 90000.0) 3602.2
('product1', 1500, 75.0) 1653.0
('product3', 1200, 8000.0) 1640.0

Coef out log
===============================================
('product1', 1500, 75.0) 8.21724195034
('product3', 1200, 8000.0) 8.15857239218
('product6', 800, 1200.0) 7.63667597387

Coef out log2
===============================================
('product1', 1500, 75.0) 11.8549742115
('product3', 1200, 8000.0) 11.7703319309
('product6', 800, 1200.0) 11.0173945564
```